# How do I replace items in a list in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have a list:

```
d: 0w 1 2 3
```

I'd like to find and replace the `0w` in the list. I was thinking I could index on the list to find them, returning a list of booleans, with:

`d . {x=0w}`

but this didn't work.

What am I doing wrong? How do I replace my `0w`'s with something friendlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find the index of each 0w you could do something like this

```
where 0w=d
```

Then if you want to replace all instances of it in d with, say 4, you can do

```
d[where 0w=d]:4f
```

Just watch out for type errors when replacing the entry

Comment: This is great, thank you! One question; why is the `where` required in the second phrase? Doing `d[0w=d]:4f` does give me unexpected behaviour, but I can't figure out why...

Comment: `where` returns the indices of the True booleans of the statement to the right. However, kdb will also interpret `d[0w=d]` in much the same way, but this is actually `d[1000b]`, so it assigns the 0 and 1 indices the value of 4f.

Comment: Using the where statement will show the index at where the condition before is met, so in our case only at 0, which is all we need. Just 0w=d returns a boolean list, i.e. 0's and 1's, which will only return the first and second entries of d.

Answer (score 2):

For multiple replacements you could alternatively use a dictionary:

```
q)d:0W 1 2 3
q)remap:0W 2!0 22
q)d^remap d
0 1 22 3
```

remap 0W to 0 and remap 2 to 22